# Change text size on a page with callback

Tags: 7, javascript

I must add buttons on my site to change font size by the user, an accessibility option. Additionally, after user changes the font size, my custom javascript function must be called as a callback after the font is increased (or decreased).

There are two modules Text Resize and Text Size in Drupal, but they don't offer a callback. There is also a RV Font Size jQuery Plugin which doesn't offer a callback either.

Before diving into any one of those modules/plugins and customizing them, maybe someone knows such an accessibility module/plugin which already has a javascript callback after font change (and of course has cookie storage as those other modules)?

Comment: Don't get it too serious, but here we have this saying: "true laziness is when you are looking all day for a ready code, when you could code it yourself in an hour". Changing font size in properly built theme can be as simple as changing class on `<body>`. [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). Why won't you just write it yourself? Wouldn't it be faster and simpler?

Comment: Ok, I've added it with jquery alone. The cookie control was easier than I thought, with jquery-cookie plugin.